# JAWS reads content of previous field

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

do you know how is it possibile that when you enter to an input, JAWS first read content of previous field? 
Is it possible to fix it or it depends on browser you use?

This is my code:

```
  <!-- Presso -->
                    <div class="{!IF(presso, 'slds-show', 'slds-hide')}" style="margin-bottom: 8px">
                        <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-1">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label">Presso</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <input id="pressoInput" class="slds-input" type="text" /> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--  Region -->
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">
                                Region
                        </label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <input id="regionInput" class="slds-input" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your code?  it's possible you inadvertently associated the previous input field as the label for your current input field, but without any code samples, we'd all be just guessing

Comment: I attached my code to post

Answer (score 1):

I see two things.  The first is your second `<input>` is disabled so I'm a little curious how you are getting your focus onto the second input.  You're not using <kbd>tab</kbd> because the browser won't let you do that.  Are you using the down arrow in JAWS to navigate through the DOM?

Second, you have `<label>` elements but you are not associating the labels with the `<input>` fields.  Just because the `<label>` is next to the `<input>` in the DOM does not mean the screen reader will read the label when focus moves to the input.  You have to tie them together.  This is done with the `for` attribute of the `<label>`.  The value of `for` should be the ID (not the NAME) property of the `<input>` as follows:

```
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="pressoInput">Presso</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
  <input id="pressoInput" class="slds-input" type="text" />
</div>
...
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="regionInput">Region</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
  <input id="regionInput" class="slds-input" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```